# Linux NI PPS Ingestion

Tags: linux, synchronization

I am trying to get my Linux Controller to ingest a pulse per second to have chrony use as a reference clock. This is all in a NI PXIe chassis. I know that I can use a timing card to send the PPS through a PXIe line as a trigger. Is there any way to identify this on the Linux OS side? I know that it'll probably be somewhere in /dev/ but when I call it with

```
cat /proc/bus/input/devices
```

I have no idea what that could be or if its even possible.

Comment: So your question is, if the backplane trigger signal is availible to Linux Userland via a device? I doubt that. And even if, a SW generated pulse - even with RT patches will still have a resonable amount of jitter and drift... if that precision is OK for you by a rapsberry pi, not an PXIe chassis :-)

Comment: PXIe is just PCIe in a different physical shape... so it just a matter of getting the right configuration for your clock card

Comment: So the big constraint is that it has to go into a PXIe chassis, so thats unfortunately not an option.
My clock card can send it to the controllers slot, but I dont think theres any way to ingest it via userland.